# Changing option in ui-codemirror

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-codemirror

I am trying to use `ui-codemirror`, and has the following code: [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/xizipunare/edit?html,output):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-codemirror/0.3.0/ui-codemirror.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="YourApp"> 
  <div ng-controller="YourController">
    <div ng-model='testCM3' ui-codemirror='{{option}}'></div>
    {{option}}<br/>
    <a href="#" ng-click="changeOption()">changeOption</a>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">     
    angular.module('YourApp', ['ui.codemirror'])
    .controller('YourController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.option = "{ lineNumbers: true }"
      $scope.testCM3 = "testCM3";
      $scope.changeOption = function () {
        if ($scope.option === "{ lineNumbers: true }") $scope.option = "{ lineNumbers: false }"
        else $scope.option = "{ lineNumbers: true }"
      }
    }])
  </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

By clicking on `changeOption` I would expect the lineNumbers to be hidden/shown. We could see that the value of `option` changes, however the codemirror does not change. Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

1. `ui-codemirror='{{option}}'` should be written as `ui-codemirror='option'`
2. `option` should be defined as an object rather than a string

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/tuquteqoma/2/edit?html,output)